# How to get a list of accounts from the new MetaMask ethereum API?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

MetaMask recently changed how they inject their API and no longer expose the `window.web3` object.

> MetaMask no longer injects web3. For details, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth is undefined`

How to get a list of accounts from the new MetaMask `ethereum` API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `window.ethereum` object injected by MetaMask or other wallets.

```js
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  // connects to MetaMask
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
} else {
  // tell the user to install an `ethereum` provider extension
}
```

This uses the new API calling an asynchronous Ethereum request on the provider. It accepts most of the Ethereum APIs and is pretty generic in the implementation.